# Is there any difference between ember serve and ember server

Tags: ember-cli

In the [ember-cli documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-ember-cli) `ember server` command is used to start the app. But we could do the same with `ember serve` command. I assume `server` is just wrapper of `serve`. Can anyone clarify more on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference, they are [aliases](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/b5aca9f454b275035756b4c53473e00b83208c73/lib/commands/serve.js#L12). Any of the following will all do the same thing:

- `ember server`
- `ember serve`
- `ember s`

Comment: So you can edit and open a pull request to the [documentation](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-04-03-getting-started.md)

Comment: because you found it, anyway I did.

Comment: There is no mention of aliases for other commands, why add them for `ember server` specifically? @ykaragol

Comment: I think they should be placed in the docs. Added "ember s, ember serve, ember d, ember t, ember g" aliases. @Kitler